# PHP extract text separated by period

Tags: php, split

I have texts in the format:

`123232.23`

`43438282.00`

I want to extract and store them into two variables $dollar and $cent.

Desired result will be as follows for the first text:

`$dollar = '123232'`

`$cent = '23'`

How can I achieve that <s>using regex</s> in PHP.

Comment: Do you have "texts" in that format, or a single string variable with that exact content?

Comment: Why do you need regular expression to do it? Why not to use php eplode function which is faster?

Comment: @user366534 Didn't know about it. Complete beginner here.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

why not just use [explode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) with [list](http://php.net/manual/en/function.list.php)

```
list($dollar, $cent) = explode('.', $text);
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is the regular expression for this:

```
$regex = '~^(?P<dollar>\d+)\.(?P<cent>\d+)$~';

if (preg_match($regex, $number, $matches)) {
  //$matches['dollar']
  //$matches['cent']
}
```

Comment: Thanks loseb. But I think I will use the Explode with List. Much simpler.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a simple explode function for it if you have only single individual strings, but if you have multiple figures in a text file and you want to extract them, you do something like this below.

For the first delimiter I used a newline character `\n. You can change it to what fits you.

```
$s = <<<ABC
123232.23
43438282.00
3333.66
ABC;

$arr = explode("\n", $s);
print_r($arr);
$exarr = array();
foreach($arr as $arv){
    $exarr[] = explode(".", $arv);
}

print_r($exarr);
```

This would parse each or the figures and output something similar to this below :

```
Array
(
    [0] => 123232.23
    [1] => 43438282.00 
    [2] => 3333.66
)
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 123232
            [1] => 23
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 43438282
            [1] => 00 
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 3333
            [1] => 66
        )

)
```

Comment: Thanks, but its just a simple single string. Will use Explode with List